# how to make Lazy Scroll on listView?

Tags: android-listview, android-asynctask, scroll, download, lazy-loading

is there any way to make lazy scrolling on a list view? i want to lazy scroll till the page ends, then show next page. my list view provides items which are articles(title,teaser and a picture)

at this moment i'am downloading all what i need and making an async task + Caching to handle the images download (lazy loading).

Any idea how to do the lazy scroll for items ?

Thank You

Comment: instead of pre-fetching all the data, use AsynkTask inside the getView() method of your adapter, that way you only fetch what you need to display now. It might be better if you have a very long list of items and you can only see a small fraction of those at any time. Regardless caching is a good idea so you don't re-fetch data you already have. But be responsible with your memory use here.

Comment: i found this excellent tutorial :
http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-dynamicaly
it did the trick.
i'm loading items per 15.
hope it helps someone else :)